# How do I have class properties (with navigational props) as entity properties? Complex types won't do

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Basically I have an entity like:

```
public class Person {
 public int PersonId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public Address Hometown { get; set; }
}
```

and a class like:

```
public class Address {
 public City City { get; set; }
 public string Province { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to have vertical join two classes and have a table with row:

```
TB_PERSON:
   PersonId PK
   Name
   City_id FK
   Province
```

Why I want this approach is, in my real project, I have same kind of data structure pattern occurring on multiple entries, in such case example would be the address class. It might easily appear in another entity.

Is it that much hard that I cannot find how to do this for days? Closest I can get is the complex types but they don't allow navigational properties in such case. I want to access and have my row data kind of structured and object oriented, thought EF would have a go. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `public Auth Auth` Your variable name and type cannot be identical.You could access `CardType` and `WhateverField` by doing `myPerson.auth.cardType` and `myPerson.auth.whateverField`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but kindly that's not what im asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComplexType SHOULD BE a solution but unfortunately:

***Complex type cannot contain navigation properties.***
[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx)

List of workarounds:

**Workaround with Table Splitting**

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

}

public class City
{
    public Int32 CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasKey(t => t.ID)
            .HasOptional(t => t.City)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("CityID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .Property(t => t.ID)
            .HasColumnName("PersonID");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("TB_PERSON");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("TB_PERSON");

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasKey(t => t.CityID)
            .ToTable("City");
    }
}
```

[Usage]

```
    using (var db = new MappingContext())
    {
        var person = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();
        var cityName = person.Address.City.Name;

        var address = db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
        var personName = address.Person.Name;
    }
```

[Database]

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
        [CityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_PERSON](
        [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Province] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [CityID] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Workaround with Table Splitting + TPC inheritance (for reusable Address class)**

*TB_CUSTOMER is another table with address columns.*

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

}

public class PersonAddress : Address
{
    public Int32 PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerAddress : Address
{
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public Int32 CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
            .HasKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .HasOptional(t => t.City)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("CityID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>()
            .HasKey(t => t.CustomerID)
            .HasOptional(t => t.City)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("CityID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Person);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("TB_PERSON");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>().ToTable("TB_PERSON");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("TB_CUSTOMER");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>().ToTable("TB_CUSTOMER");

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasKey(t => t.CityID)
            .ToTable("City");
    }
}
```

**Workaround with IAddress**

```
public class Person : IAddress
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IAddress Address { get { return this; } }
}

public interface IAddress
{
    string Province { get; set; }
    City City { get; set; }

}

public class City
{
    public Int32 CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(t => t.PersonID)
            .HasOptional(t => t.City)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("CityID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("TB_PERSON");

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasKey(t => t.CityID)
            .ToTable("City");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I didn't know Table splitting. But this class is occurring more than one entry so If I go for table splitting, I have to do that for each other entity.

Comment: +1 for "Table splitting". With this model, also removing the navigation property from Address to Person (with complex type you don't have this feature), you need to have an Address class for each entity that use it (for example one for Person like in this case, one for Customer and so on) am I right?

Comment: You are right, Address doesn't have to have navigation property to Person ( to do this configuration for person should end with .WithRequiredPrincipal(); ).
To reuse Address class in other mapping ( eg. Customer ) i think we need to combine Table Splitting with some inheritance strategy for Address ( eg. TPC ).
Reusable Address class will be the base class. PersonAddress and CustomerAddress will have additional properties for Person and Customer and they will be mapped with Table Splitting strategy.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. I think that this table splitting would make PersonId appearring twice meanwhile if I could just do a single table with fields: (id, addr, prov, etc... ) that would save some database size. But I guess there's no way that aspnet is offering right now. The solutions I came up since I asked this question is I might create an interface to force the entity to apply an IAddress with fields. Then I might cast it like (entity as IAddress).provinceId and still have access to address properties. If you'd like, you may work on my solution and I'll give you the bounty

Comment: Using IAddress interface in every entity with adddress columns will mix address properties with properties of that entity ( just as bubi wrote in his inheritance workaround). I will add it as another example.
PersonId in Address class can have other name ( which i will change in above example for better understanding ) but it is still one mapped to one column in TB_PERSON.

Comment: Thanks for providing such wide solution to this problem. I hope in the future this will provide solutions to people trying to deal with this problem. Also +1 for clever usage of non-mapping property, public IAddr addr { get { return this; }

Answer (score 1):

There are also 2 more workaround (not solutions) in addition to Table splitting.

**Inheritance**

Create Address class and inherit from it in every class that should have an address.
Address properties are mixed with other properties (so actually I think I would not apply this solution in your case).

**1-1 relationship**
(or n-1 relationship if more entities can share same address)

Model:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

The context:

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    { }

    public DbSet<ClassA> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassB> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().HasOptional(c => c.ClassA).WithOptionalDependent(c => c.ClassB);
    }
}
```

DDL Statements:

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [ClassAs] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Description] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [ClassAs] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ClassAs_9cd06620] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [ClassBs] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Description] text null
, [ClassA_Id] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [ClassBs] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ClassBs_9cd06620] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_ClassA_Id] ON [ClassBs] ([ClassA_Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [ClassBs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ClassBs_ClassAs_ClassA_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ClassA_Id]) REFERENCES [ClassAs] ([Id])
```

In this second case you can remove ClassB.ClassA navigation property so you can share ClassB across multiple types. The issue here is that you have 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

Almost every complex navigation is possible with fluent api.

Google These:  Fluent Api and EntityTypeConfiguration

Comment: Thanks I'll look for these, meanwhile you could improve your answer and provide a solution so I can mark your reply as accepted answer